# formatting a drive to FAT32 with mkdosfs, need some info

Tags: command-line, hard-drive, format

I'd like to know how I can specify the cluster size when using `mkdosfs /dev/sdx -F 32`. I read somewhere that if you want to format it with a 32kb cluster size, this is the command:

`mkdosfs /dev/sdx -s 64 -F 32 -I`

But, what if I want to format it with a 64kb cluster size? How can I do it? Can someone explain the proper usage of `mkdosfs /dev/sdx -s XX` in plain words (I'm not a native english speaker)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the command is:

```
sudo mkdosfs /dev/sdXX -s 128 -F 32
```

Since you want 64KB clusters, and the `-s` means sectors per cluster so, you need 128 sectors, because 128*512 byes = 64KB, making a cluster.

If you want the whole disk to contain a single partition, you would use `-I` option. So, the command becomes,

```
sudo mkdosfs /dev/sdX -s 128 -F 32 -I
```

<sup>Credit goes to [this Ubuntu forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=903612)</sup>

Comment: thanks, this was exactly the info i was looking for, i mean the `sectors*bytes` thing...

Comment: Note that Windows older versions don't support 64K or larger cluster sizes so if you need cross compatibility you might not want to do this: See http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/FAT#FAT32

Comment: I used to format 64k on WinXP for DIOS MIOS (fastest setting btw)... not sure what I did to enable the selection though... >_>

Comment: I have a partition with type `W95 FAT32 (LBA)`. Do I still need `mkdosfs` if I want to use the `default` format? Maybe with `fdisk` I only prepare the partition to `fat32` but with `mkdosfs` I create the filesystem.